# Shared login between a php and a .net sites on same domain

Tags: php, .net

We're working on a website for a client and we are developing the front-end products website using PHP, and there is a subdomain called "store" for the online ordering functionality. But the store sub-domain is built with .net.

How can I keep the user logged in when they go to the store? Both the front-end and the store are using the same authentication service so that's not an issue. But I don't have experience with .net so I can figure out which are the session cookie values. So I would set them to be domain-specific and it would work.

Comment: Yip, stor logins/sessions in DB and/or use cookies - usually using both will work. So you will have .NET code to interrogate session DB using session id in cookie and vice-versa.

Comment: I'm not sure if PHP and .NET can share **SESSION** information, but they should have no problem accessing the same **COOKIE** as long as the cookie is valid.

Answer (score 1):

I would store sessions in database and both instances would user the same database for reading session data by session ID read from the shared cookie between www.site.com and store.site.com.

Answer (score 0):

Either store information about login on the server somewhere.

Or you can just add a cookie to the user's browser and read that in both placed.